# How can I include a SQL Function in my Code First EF query?

Tags: oracle, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have a simple question.

Is it possible to wrap a SQL function in "EF Code first" code such that I can execute it as part of my other LINQ -> EF queries?

We have a SQL function that does some hardcore work on the DB. We give it a reference number, and its returns a nice formatted string based on the reference. What I want to do is add it into the db query, but I'm not sure how to go about it.

For info, this would be the SQL that I would use (made simpler):

```
select t.ref, getrefstring(t.ref) from transactions t;
```

I dont want to write the SQL by hand and use the SQLQuery command, as the actual SQL is extensive, and I really dont want to have to go back to using SQL, as that gets messy when I have to map all of the fields back into C# again.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Cheers, Nick

Comment: possible duplicate of [define scalar function with ef4.1 code first?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7716859/define-scalar-function-with-ef4-1-code-first)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about creating a view:

```
create view transactions_view as
select t.ref, getrefstring(t.ref), ... (other cols you may want)
from transactions t;
```