# Linq to entity framework with try_cast

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I need to refactor my app, changing magic sql strings with linq expressions. 
How convert following SQL-Query to LINQ

```
select et from tiporazmers where try_cast(et as float)>@param1`
```

Note: I need to filter on database level, no filter collections in memory!

Any suggestions are helpful, thanks!

Comment: You mean to use it as LinqToSql or just pass it to the server?

Comment: what's type of `et` in DB?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Entity Framework/Linq EXpression converting from string to int](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16694716/entity-framework-linq-expression-converting-from-string-to-int)

Comment: @Backs that link is out of date. The answers there do not involve building `Expression` tree with `Expression.Convert`. I believe that's was because at that time `Expression.Convert` had not been supported in EF. But now (at least since EF5) we can build Expression tree using `Expression.Convert`. BTW, I downvoted 2 answers there suggesting to use `Convert.ToInt32` (about a month ago)

Comment: You cannot do this without changing the database. You should change type of column to numeric type in table, or create view with cast and select from that view.