# Sorting a List of Strings as Integers in LINQ C#

Tags: c#, linq, sorting, entity-framework-6

I have a List of Objects (`RunSummary`) sorted by a `UniqueId` column, then `RunNo` column. But `UniquId` objects are of type `String`. I want to sort by `UniqueId` as `Integer` objects (not as 1,10,11,3 but 1,3,10,11). Here is my code:

```
public List<RunSummary> GetRunSummariesForUniqueIds(List<String> uniqueIds)
{
    using (var context = new ELSORegistryEntities())
    {
        context.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;

        List<RunSummary> runSummaries = context.RunSummaries
            .Where(param => uniqueIds.Contains(param.UniqueId))
            .OrderBy(param => param.UniqueId)
            .ThenBy(param => param.RunNo)
            .ToList<RunSummary>);              

        return runSummaries;
    }
}
```

I have tried with

```
List<RunSummary> runSummaries = context.RunSummaries
    .Where(param => uniqueIds.Contains(param.UniqueId))
    .OrderBy(param => Convert.ToInt32(param.UniqueId))
    .ThenBy(param => param.RunNo)
    .ToList<RunSummary>();
```

but it doesn't work. How do I sort in LINQ?

Comment: What specifically isn't working?  Are you getting an exception?  Or if you get incorrect results what are they?

Comment: @juharr I didn't think you could use a function like `int.Parse(param.UniqueId)` inside a `DBContext` query?

Comment: i guess, that you can't use Convert.ToInt32 in LINQ query to DB, but give us an answer what's wrong..

Comment: Possibly related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16694716/entity-framework-linq-expression-converting-from-string-to-int

Comment: You could do ToList before sorting, and use the int parsing logic after that ...

Comment: @Sam.C Better yet to use `AsEnumerable`.

Comment: I got an exception :" LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Int32 ToInt32(System.String)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression."

Comment: I can't agree with the closure of this topic. The given answer on the "selected" post is not the correct answer. It works but it isn't correct.

Comment: Why are the `UniqueId` values stores as strings? If they're really integers, then they should have a different data type in your schema.

Answer (score 2):

you can't use Convert.ToInt32 inside the query, you should order after the query

```
List<RunSummary> runSummaries = context.RunSummaries.Where(param => uniqueIds.
Contains(param.UniqueId)).ToList<RunSummary>()
.OrderBy(param => Convert.ToInt32(param.UniqueId))
.ThenBy(param => param.RunNo).ToList();
```

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately, I got an FormatException: "Input string was not in a correct format."